# How to print Array of Objects Value, if Object Key pair Values are different

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
    const Court= [
    
    {
    title: ' INTERLOCUTARY APPLICATION(s)',
       
        content: [
          {
            RegNo: '784/2020',
            Particular: 'EXEMPTION FROM FILING O.T',
            Remark: '-',
            FiledBy: 'PRATIBHA JAIN',
            FilingDate: '03-01-2020',
            SrNo: '1',
            Status: 'P',
            EnterOn: '03-01-2020 15:12:42',
          },
        ],
    
    }

{
    
     title:'Case Details',
    
    content :[
    
    {
    
       DiaryNo:
              '44424/2019 Filed on 09-12-2019 03:42 PM [SECTION: IV-C]PENDING ',
            
    CaseNo:
              'SLP(C) No.000033 -/ 2020 Registered on 03-01-2020 (Verified ON 06-01-2020)',
            
    Present_LastListedOn: '28-02-2020 [REGISTER(J)- II]',
            
    Status_Stage:
              'Pending -(Motion Hearing [After NOTICE (FOR ADMISSION)- CIVIL CASES]) List before court/bench-ord at 28-02-2020',
           
     Category: '-',
         
       Act: '-',
    
    }]
    
    }
    
    ]

I want to print this title and Content data using single component that is Accordion in react native i use and inside that accordion i use Grid to create table and in that table i want to show may content data in key Value pair.
```

following is Accordion code-

```
    const App = () => {
  const [activeSections, setActiveSections] = useState([]);
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
  const setSections = sections => {
    
    setActiveSections(sections.includes(undefined) ? [] : sections);
  };
  const renderHeader = (section, _, isActive) => {
    //Accordion Header view
    return (
      <View
        duration={400}
        style={[styles.header, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}
        transition="backgroundColor">
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{section.title}</Text>
        <Arrow name="down" size={25} color="#FFFFFF"></Arrow>
      </View>
    );
  };
const renderContent = (section, _, isActive) => {
    //Accordion Content view
    return (
      <View
        duration={400}
        style={[styles.content, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}
        transition="backgroundColor">
        {section.content.map((d, i) => {
          //console.log('d >>> ', d);
          return (
            <View key={i}>
              <Grid style={{borderWidth: 1}}>
                <Col>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>
                      Reg.No/I.A No
                    </Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>
                      Particular
                    </Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>Remark</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>Filed By</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>
                      FilingDate
                    </Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>Sr No</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>Status</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={[styles.cell, styles.titletxt]}>Enter On</Text>
                  </Row>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.RegNo}</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.Particular}</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.Remark}</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.FiledBy}</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.FilingDate}</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.SrNo}</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.Status}</Text>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Text style={styles.cell}>{d.EnterOn}</Text>
                  </Row>
                </Col>
              </Grid>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          {/*Code for Accordion/Expandable List starts here*/}
          <View style={{margin: 8}}>
            <Accordion
              activeSections={activeSections}
              sections={Court}
              touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
              renderHeader={renderHeader}
              renderContent={renderContent}
              //Content Component(View) to render
              duration={400}
              //Duration for Collapse and expand
              onChange={setSections}
              //setting the state of active sections
              style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C3C3C5'}}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

I am only  able to print the Content data with Key Value pair for Interlocutary not able to print for Case details Content Data  please tell me how to reuse the accordion component to print the case details content??

but title value print properly now issue with title only with content Data .

Comment: Use `map` to loop over values again to get the different values

Comment: Actually I use map function see the renderContent code in that i use map function for showing content data

Comment: Yes. But your content array object has different fields. use map on `d` again to get the different values.